# Change parameters of random number generator

Tags: c++, boost, random

I am using the `boost::random` to generate random velocity values and I want to change the mean and variance in response to user input.

I am using the following:

```
typedef boost::mt19937 RNG;
static RNG rng();

typedef boost::normal_distribution<double> DIST;
DIST dist_east(vel_e, sigma);
DIST dist_north(vel_n, sigma);

boost::variate_generator<RNG, DIST> east(rng, dist_east);
boost::variate_generator<RNG, DIST> north(rng, dist_north);

velocity.east = east();
velocity.north = north();
```

My problem is that I only get one value returned from the two variate generators each time it gets called. The values change when I change vel_e, vel_n or sigma but otherwise, I get the same value returned.

I tried making the dist_east, dist_north, east and north objects static but I can't change the parameters after construction.

Is there a way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Do you mean you create the generators each time you want to generate a number? If so, don't do that! Create them once and then call them repeatedly.

Comment: @Neil Yes, that is my current strategy. My version of boost (1.20) (and nor does the latest (1.46)) doesn't give methods to change the parameters. I'm rethinking my design so I recreate the objects less frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the quickest way is just to have a normal distribution with sigma 1 and mean 0. In that way, you can get values from any normal distribution just multiplying for your new sigma and adding the mean.

```
y = mean + sigma * x
```

Answer (score 3):

If *U* is a normally distributed random variable with mean 0 and variance 1, then

```
V = mu + sigma * U
```

is normally distributed with mean *mu* and variance *sigma²*.

So all you need is to generate standard normal random variables (mean 0, stdev 1) and scale them properly.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this property of normal distributions. Sadly I can't mark both your answer and Matteo's as accepted. dan

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be approaching the problem the wrong way. Instead of modifying the random number generator so that you have the mean and deviation you want, you should instead make the random generator always give you a uniform distribution. Then, make your own function that takes as input this uniform distribution, and gives as output the desired distribution.

If you want normal distributions, you can see [in the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution) that it's quite easy to generate a normal distribution from a uniform one.

Edit : Here's some pseudo code (I have no idea how the boost random generator works)

```
generateNormalDistribution(mean, deviation)  
    X = boost::uniformGeneratorBetween0and1  
    Y = boost::uniformGeneratorBetween0and1  
    return [sqrt(-2*ln(X)) * cos(2*pi*Y)]*deviation + mean
```

Comment: If I may, inquire, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: 1) it is even not the right way to do it (you can avoid the trig) 2) it has wrong tails (subtle but true) 3) there are way better methods 4) it is woefully inefficient. Google for "ziggurat method" or "ratio-of-uniforms" for *good* ways to generate a normal deviate. Also, OP should use boost to draw his/her standard normal distribution, since it is already set up.

Comment: 1) Right, but it's just below in the link I gave :P 2) Nice to know it! 3) I'm in the "Keep it simple" mood, but I guess it depends on the application 4) It's a bit redundant with the rest but anyway, the `mu + sigma * U` is quite clearly the answer here!